# Why is count(*) slow, when explain knows the answer?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, amazon-rds

I am using MySQL InnoDB. The table has **10 Million records**. I am trying to execute the below query and it takes too much time to execute.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM abc_test WHERE id = ? AND parent_id IS NULL AND user_status IN (?,?,?,?);`

Can anyone please help? The following are the details for the same.

1. Cloud: AWS
2. Database: MySQL RDS(r3.2xlarge)
3. Version : 5.6.34

**Table Structure (Total 50 Columns)**

- id int(11)
- parent_id int(11)
- user_status tinyint(4)
- created datetime
- modified datetime

Comment: Do you have any indexes on table?

Comment: What indexes do you have? It would be great if you share the execution plan.

Comment: EXPLAIN takes the info about COUNT from statistic table which value is approximate. Whereas the query gives precise result.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes. I do have the indexes.

Comment: @VladimirPligin I do have around 8 indexes for multiple filters and parent_id is one of them.

Comment: @Akina Okay. I will do and revert. Thanks

Comment: Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is needed to help you.

Comment: @RickJames Sure would do.

Answer (score 1):

This is partially explained in the [documentation on explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html):

> - rows (JSON name: rows)
>
> The rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must examine to execute the query.
>
> For InnoDB tables, this number is an estimate, and may not always be exact.

I believe the reason is because `explain` takes the value from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_ROWS` column.  The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html) further emphasizes there:

> `TABLE_ROWS`
>
> The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the exact count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40% to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate count.

In other words, when you use `SELECT COUNT(*)`, MySQL generates the same query plan regardless of the storage engine.  If you happen to know that it is safe to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, then you can use that value -- either because you are not using InnoDB or because an approximate value is good enough.